# how am i supposed to take a user input of a path and use that path in my program

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pyo

my code:

```
enter def  play():
import pyo
s = pyo.Server()
s.boot()
s.start()
s.setInputDevice(4)
s.setOutputDevice(4)
p = input("path: ")
play_audio1 = pyo.SfPlayer(path=p, speed=[1.25, 1.25])
play_audio1.out()
s.gui(locals(), exit=False)
play()
```

code here
so the problem im facing is, i want to take path as a user input and play the audio file. help me out. for now i have only tried taking it was a user input and storing it in a var and use it but it dosent work.

Comment: what does the error say? FileNotFound?

Comment: This is not a valid Python code: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @MichaelHsi    play()
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\test1.py", line 9, in play
    play_audio1 = pyo.SfPlayer(path=p, speed=[1.25, 1.25])
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyo\lib\players.py", line 112, in __init__
    _snd_size, _dur, _snd_sr, _snd_chnls, _format, _type = sndinfo(path[0])
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Comment: do a test run, before using pyo.SfPlayer, open your file using open(path, 'rb') and see if it throws FileNotFound

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. I have provided input from user as follows and i was able to get gui for audio.

path: C:/Users/anil/Downloads/M1F1-AlawC-AFsp.aif

If you are still facing issues. Kindly check below things.

```
p = p.replace('"','').replace("'","")
```

Note: Kindly try with '.aif' file. It should possibly work for you

Comment: yes it worked, turns out the .aif file i used was corrupted

Comment: @aaditya If the question is now irrelevant, please consider removing it. That way people won't try to solve it, or stumble upon it while looking for their own answer.